# outputting the middle element(s) of matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix, output, floor, ceil

I'm really stuck on this problem: Please help.
Create a code that takes a matrix as an input and outputs the middle
element of the matrix. (hint: think about floor and ceiling functions)

Comment: OK, you're stuck. Can you show us what attempts you've made so far, and where/why they fail? How about trying "output the middle element of a vector", which would be easier but require the same basic machinery? (Does the problem specify what to do if there are an even number of rows and/or columns, in which case there are several reasonable answers?)

Comment: It will not make your better if Stackoverflow will do your homework for you without any attempt from you. [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: ##Problem4 Middle element of Matrix Function UNFINISHED

matrixf = function(a, b, x, y) {
f = matrix(a:b, x, y)
return(f)
len = x*y
evensq = seq(from=2, to=len, by=2)
if
}

Comment: This is what I have so far

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%/%` - integer division and `%% 2` - modulo 2 operation to extract central element(s) depending on amount of columns and rows (odd or even). Please see below:

```
middle <- function(m) {
  nr <- nrow(m)
  nc <- ncol(m)
  if (nr %% 2 == 0) {
    ns <- c(nr %/% 2, nr %/% 2 + 1) 
  } else {
    ns <- nr %/% 2 + 1
  }

  if (nc %% 2 == 0) {
    ms <- c(nc %/% 2, nc %/% 2 + 1)
  } else {
    ms <- nc %/% 2 + 1
  }
  m[ns, ms]
}


m <- matrix(1:16, nrow = 4)
m
middle(m)
```

Output for test matrix (4x4):

```
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    5    9   13
[2,]    2    6   10   14
[3,]    3    7   11   15
[4,]    4    8   12   16
> middle(m)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    6   10
[2,]    7   11
```